Potential arbitrage opportunity or fallacy?
Suppose we have two European options with the same expiration: a call priced at $c$ with strike price $K_1$ and a put priced at $p$ with $K_2 (>K_1)$. Further, suppose the zero-points of the two payoff curves  intersect on the x-axis, i.e. $K_1+c=K_2-p$. Then, wouldn't the ensuing portfolio always have a non-negative payoff? Is there some theoretical justification to prevent this from happening?

A nonnegative payoff alone isn’t sufficient for an arbitrage, for example: a straddle. The portfolio must be zero cost as well.

I am accounting for the cost in the payoff, so for example the payoff for the call is $-c$ till the stock price reaches $K_1$ and increasing linearly thereafter, and so on.

The ‘pure payoff” diagram (excluding option premia) for this structure shows that the payoff is always at least $K_2 - K_1 $ Therefore the total premium $c+p$ must be at least $K_2 -K_1$ so yes, a simple arbitrage argument shows this condition should not occur.
